# Master Detail view in xtragrid devexpress

Tags: mysql, winforms, xtragrid

I have a WinForm solution in c# and .NET4. I use Mysql and ListDataSource for fill data in xtragrid. I would to create a detail view in relationship with master view. I had found some examples but I just can not in this work. You help me please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to see what kind of code you've already tried in order to accomplish this task with your Listdatasource. I tend to keep my master and detail grids separate, repopulating the child when the focused row is changed, so I wonder if this kind of pattern would help. It presumes master and detail would be linked by a parentID key in both tables.

```
private void Parentgv_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e)

{

int parentID = Parentgv.GetRowCellValue(Parentgv.FocusedRowHandle, colparentID);

childgc.datasource = childtable(c=>c.parentID == parentID);

}
```

Comment: I agree with you in maintaining the master detail grid in separate, but I just can not understand the logic to use to retrieve the data in the view child starting from the parent view. Can you please let me know if you need more information? Below I'll show you a piece of code that works, that uses ListaDataSource :ArrayList listDataSource = new ArrayList(); while (reader.Read())
            {
                listDataSource.Add(new FlaWeeklyProductionFab(
                    reader["sezione"].ToString(),reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose(); gridControl15.DataSource = listDataSource;

Comment: tell me if it is not clear what I wrote before please

Comment: Sorry, this isn't clear to me. I'm not seeing where you've established the foreign key relationship between the parent and child tables.

Comment: this is what I can not understand. The key ParentID you to show me an example I call it at runtime or should be that of the database? I'm a bit confused ... you make me an example please? thanks in advance

Comment: I presume that you're working with two tables, in a parent child relationship... either one to many or one to one. Is that correct? Can you present the schema here?

Comment: Hello Craig and thanks for the reply. How about if we start from the beginning? I have studied the problem better, I created an ArrayList which is populated from my query, but when I try to expand a row I get an error of NullReferenceException in line Application.Run (new Form1 ()); program.cs file. What has happened now? Thanks in advance ...

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you. The information you've been providing lacks any actual data rows, and is insufficient for proceeding, so I suggest we stop. Have you tried the client support at the devexpress site? They're generally very good at providing sample projects.

Comment: I Craig, I have solved on DevExpress site. I have to fire gridView1_MasterRowGetRelationName event, and finally now all works. Thanks so much for your replies.